# Send close signal to SSH immediately on password prompt

Tags: bash, ssh

I am currently running a server test with the following command:

```
echo ^C |ssh -q root@${server}
if [ 0 -ne $? ]; then
  echo "==> Failed to connect..."; continue
fi
```

Unfortunately it does not look like my `^C` is closing the connection immediately after a password prompt which is what I was expecting. Is there a better way to write this to test for an ssh connection without hanging on a prompt?

Comment: `0 != =$(echo $?)` ??? I'd be surprized if that doesn't generate an error msg. In any case, you can reduce that to `if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then` .And sorry to say, I think your original thesis will not work. Its complicated, so if you can't advance your code quickly, start reading about `expect` to support your testing. Good luck.

Comment: @Academia echo $'\cc' |ssh root@hostname didn't seem to work =/

Comment: @shellter yeah, bad coding i know ;) changed to reflect what you said

Comment: What specifically are you testing for here? ssh will exit with a failure code if you fail to connect _or_ if you fail to authenticate.

Comment: Testing whether the VPN is working for all sites before continuing with the rest of my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On unix systems, `^C` kills a process because the TTY interface sends an interrupt signal to the process when the user types ^C. A literal ^C on standard input (read from a file or printed to a pipe from another process's output) is just a regular character.

You could suppress password authentication by running ssh like this:

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -q root@${server}
```

ssh will exit with a failure code if it fails to authenticate using something other than a password. This failure code is indistinguishable from a failure to connect, so this may not be what you want.

If you're mainly interested in connectivity to the remote SSH server port, you don't have to use the actual ssh program to test. You could do this test with [`nc` (netcat)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) for example:

```
$ nc -z localhost 22
$ echo $?
0
$ nc -z localhost 11122
$ echo $?
1
```

The `-z` flag tells netcat to test connectivity to the specified host and port without sending or receiving any data. You could structure your test like this:

```
if nc -z localhost 22
then
    : success
else
    echo Connection to ${server} failed
fi
```

Comment: @ehime : This is what I meant in my comment by "It's complicated" ; -) Good luck to all.