# how to script confirming access on remote host

Tags: ssh

I've got a list of accounts/machines that I need to check that I have working access.
So far I have written a for loop around the list.
But when I run ssh for a machine where my .ssh2 public key is not there yet, I get:

```
> /usr/bin/ssh someuser@somemachine groups
Password:
```

and it hangs waiting for the password.
How do I invoke ssh to fail instead of asking for a password?

I looked at -n option but that is for the remote cmd after password.
I tried < /dev/null but it knows it's a tty and still asks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this works to disable attempting to ask for the password.

/usr/bin/ssh -o AllowedAuthentications=publickey ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a pretty good answer here: [Send close signal to SSH immediately on password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554111/send-close-signal-to-ssh-immediately-on-password-prompt)

To whit,

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -q user@somemachine
```

These both work for me on Ubuntu:

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -q user@somemachine
ssh -o BatchMode=yes -q  user@somemachine
```

Comment: I just tried this because it more clearly describes what I want but ssh still asked for a password.  Which is very odd given the name of the option.  Perhaps this is supplier/version dependent?  I don't see that option described in man ssh_config or sshd_config though it still accepts it and doesn't complain.

Comment: Try "man ssh" -- this is not about altering your ssh_config file.